# Wordpress Php function passing variables through ajax to save user meta

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, variables

**All the code has been updated since I last posted.**
I am having trouble writing this piece of code. This is for a client. What it's supposed to do is when a user is logged into the website as a customer. They fill out the criteria for product: Year, Make, Model, Option 1. This generates the list of products my client has. He wants a button to save the customer's criteria so they can click on it in their user section to pull up the products without having to go through the search again.

I'm having trouble with the ajax and passing the criteria. So in my js file this is what I have for the ajax function:

```
function ajaxAddVehicleMeta(){

var userId = ''; // fill this in to somehow acquire the userID client-side...
var year = '<?php echo $year; ?>';
var make= '<?php echo $make; ?>';
var model= '<?php echo $model; ?>';
var option1= '<?php echo $option1; ?>';
var stdoropt= '<?php echo $stdoropt; ?>'; 

jQuery.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
        data: { 
            action: 'saveVeh', 
            userId: userId, 
            year:year, 
            make:make, 
            model:model, 
            option1:option1, 
            stdoropt:stdoropt },
        url: comm_custom.ajaxurl, //this is the url found in functions
        success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: User ID " + userId + "." );
   },
   error: function(msg){
      alert( "Data not saved: User ID " + userId + ".");
   }

});
}
```

In my functions.php file I have:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_saveVeh', 'saveVeh' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_saveVeh', 'saveVeh' ); 
function saveVeh(){

$year = $_POST['year'];
$make = $_POST['make'];
$model = $_POST['model'];
$option1 = $_POST['option1'];
$stdoropt = $_POST['stdoropt'];

    //if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        if(!$user_id):
                echo 'failed, not logged in';
                exit;
            endif;  

        if($year){
            $vehicle1 = $year.' '.$make.' '.$model.' '.$option1.' / '.$stdoropt;
        }else if($_POST['width']){
            $vehicle1 = $_POST['width']. ' ' .$_POST['height']. ' ' .$_POST['rim'];
        }
            update_user_meta( $user_id, '_vehicle1', $vehicle1);            
    //}
```

On the page is this link: **Updated**

```
<a href="#" onclick="ajaxAddVehicleMeta()" class="vehicle-btn" >Save Search Criteria</a>
```

I put an alert and it's telling me its a success. But It didn't save it in the User Meta. Is there something I am doing wrong?

the comm_custom.ajaxurl is admin-ajax.php in the enqueue scripts and localizing it.

Comment: `data: { action: 'saveVeh', userId: userId }` you are not posting anything here that you are picking up ($_POST in php). Also have you add_action the function to ajax_nopriv?

Comment: I have added the ajax_nopriv action. What do I have to change in the data part?

Comment: well at the moment you are only passing $_POST['userId'], so your post values in php are null. But thats not your main issue, is_logged in must be returning false otherwise you would be saving a empty db entry. remove it to test.

Comment: I tried adding in the $_POST['tire-year'] and such like that, but I get an error like "userId: userId, tire-year: tire-year ..." it was saying they were undefined... Am I suppose to add something more in the actual link in the onclick?

Comment: you need to set the variables before passing it in. If you just want to test use tire-year: 'tire-year' etc .......actually use tireyear instead

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues in the code above..js variables need to be set before using or else they throw a error.

js

```
        function ajaxAddVehicleMeta(){

        var tireyear= jQuery('#tireyear').val(); // select id of input change to whatever it actually is
        var width= jQuery('#width').val(); // select id of input change to whatever it actually is

        jQuery.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
                data: { 
                    action: 'saveVeh', 
                    userId: userId, 
                    tireyear: tireyear,
                    width: width            
                    },
                url: comm_custom.ajaxurl, //this is the url found in functions
                success: function(msg){
             alert( "Data Saved: User ID " + userId + "." );
           },
           error: function(msg){
              alert( "Data not saved: User ID " + userId + ".");
           }

        });
    }
```

php

```
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_saveVeh', 'saveVeh' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_saveVeh', 'saveVeh' ); 

    function saveVeh(){


            $user_id = get_current_user_id();

            if(!$user_id):
                echo 'failed, not logged in';
                exit;
            endif;  

            if($_POST['tire-year']){
                $vehicle1 = $_POST['tire-year'].' '.$_POST['make'].' '.$_POST['model'].' '.$_POST['option1'].' / '.$_POST['stdoropt'];
            }else if($_POST['width']){
                $vehicle1 = $_POST['width']. ' ' .$_POST['height']. ' ' .$_POST['rim'];
            } else {
                echo 'failed, no data';
                exit;
            }

            update_user_meta( $user_id, '_vehicle1', $vehicle1);            

            echo $user_id; // you need to return something for ajax success to pick up..
            exit;
    }
```

html: -- you have no arguments in your function to pass values into. so leave them blank..

```
<a href="#" onclick="ajaxAddVehicleMeta()" class="vehicle-btn" >Save Vehicle 1</a>
```

Comment: The page this link is on, is a results page. The link is to save the options to of the results: year, make, model, option1... Would this change the var structure?

Comment: yes...this is all simple js, ignore the ajax tag for the moment. Set whatever variables you want to send to the server within the function. jQuery(selector).val() will pull the values from the html fields your information is in. If they are already set by php you can echo them into your js e.g. var variable= <?php echo $variable; ?>. Then create data fields as above (see tyreyear for an example) and then this is obviously available on the server using $_POST['tyreyear'].

Comment: it looks ok, is it working? Also you need to do sanitize_text_field() when handling the $_POST vars on the server side.

Comment: It's working. And the where do I put in sanitize_text_field? In the javascript code or on the page itself?

Comment: its a wordpress php  function. e.g. `$var= sanitize_text_field($_POST['var']); ` , use it in your saveVeh function

Comment: How are you getting the value of userId in this answer?

Comment: its not populated in the example but easy enough to pop into the html somewhere and grab it for ajax.